# Помогите разобраться с bootstrap шаблонами в django

Tags: python, django

Скачал шаблон (его можно посмотреть в моем dropbox)
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rteqlwm4df18qg8/AABbNEj-8KGGaKAxUGjBJTrVa?dl=0
Там лежит несколько файлов и папок, мак ось меня не интересует соответсвенно
я зашел в папку html и там такой расклад.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом django я сделал

pip install django-bootstrap3

соответственно в django app news папка templates а в ней папка news
 в нее положил все html файлы из шаблона и 4 папки css fonts img js
Запустил сервер настроил юрлы и вьюхи в шаблон дописал

```
    {% load bootstrap3 %}
<script src="{% bootstrap_jquery_url %}"></script>
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
```

в settings.py все подключил (и bootstrap 3 и news)
Запускаю открываю в браузере и вижу что шрифты подтянулись а вот js и картинки нет.
Помогите если есть возможность и время!

Comment: `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Спасибо попробую,и еще понял что папка lдолжна называться static а не templates